# h1 display: inline-block messes up floats. potential chrome bug?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

i have an odd issue that's only showing up in chrome. version 42.0.2311.135 in case that's part of the issue. internet explorer and firefox render the page properly.

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/53m8arfy/

```css
div.left {float: left;}
div.right {float: right;}
h1.broke {border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2; display: inline-block; width: 100%;}
h1.works {border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;}
```

```html
<h1 class="broke">header</h1>
<div class="left">
    <p>short content</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <p>long content</p>
    <p>long content</p>
    <p>long content</p>
    <p>long content</p>
    <p>long content</p>
    <p>long content</p>
</div>
<br style="clear: both;" />
<div class="left">
    <p>short content</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <p>long content</p>
    <p>long content</p>
    <p>long content</p>
    <p>long content</p>
    <p>long content</p>
    <p>long content</p>
</div>
<br style="clear: both;" />
<div class="left">
    <p>short content</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <p>long content</p>
    <p>long content</p>
    <p>long content</p>
    <p>long content</p>
    <p>long content</p>
    <p>long content</p>
</div>
<br style="clear: both;" />
```

the h1 at the top is set to class="broke". if you're seeing what i am, all the floats below are messed up.

changing the h1 at the top to class="works" [which removes inline-block and associated width] makes everything happy.

my google-fu isn't able to find any bug report or anyone else with this issue, though it's not the easiest thing to search for.

Comment: I have that version of chrome and it looks fine to me. Maybe you have a bad install?

Comment: It works when you replace `<br style="clear:both" />` with `<div style="clear:both"></div>`. Seems to be a specialty in how Chrome handles `<br>`.

Comment: Why are you using non-semantic `<br style="clear: both;" />` instead of adding the `clear: both` on `div.left`?

Comment: @Alexander you should add that as the answer. I believe the issue here is that `<br>` is an inline element.

Comment: @Vlad: i'm trying to remember why i chose inline as opposed to naked block. i think it was for the forced break afterward.

Comment: @Andrew: if it's a bad install, it's on both my linux box and my windows vm.

Comment: @Alexander: that's all well and good, but i have an entire site with this <left> <right> <br> <left> <right> <br> format. going in and changing all the <br style="clear: both; /> to <div> would be a hell of a project all because chrome seems to be misbehaving and i'm forced to dev on a system where i can't run scripts.

Comment: @j08691: that's a good question / suggestion. the answer is that i'm not comfortable enough with floats. putting {float: left; clear: both;} on a single element seems like an oxymoron.

Comment: It's not, and it would seem to resolve the problem.

Comment: @zee your lack in good software seems to be a major issue. Every better editor can do a search and replace over multiple files. Otherwise, it is unsuitable for development.

Comment: @Alexander: tell that to my fortune 100 company that forces me to work on a content system stuck on html 4.0. [not even 4.1] that is to say, i agree with your assertions, but my hands are tied.

Comment: @j08691: +1 to that. thanks for teaching me. i think that's the best proposed solution so far.

Comment: Let me know if you'd like me to post that as an answer.

Comment: @j08691: i'd vote for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend removing the ,`<br>` elements as they serve no semantic meaning, and adding the `clear:both` rule to the `div.left` rules you currently have:

```css
div.left {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
}
div.right {
  float: right;
}
h1.broke {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
h1.works {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="works">header</h1>
<div class="left">
  <p>short content</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <p>long content</p>
  <p>long content</p>
  <p>long content</p>
  <p>long content</p>
  <p>long content</p>
  <p>long content</p>
</div>
<div class="left">
  <p>short content</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <p>long content</p>
  <p>long content</p>
  <p>long content</p>
  <p>long content</p>
  <p>long content</p>
  <p>long content</p>
</div>
<div class="left">
  <p>short content</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <p>long content</p>
  <p>long content</p>
  <p>long content</p>
  <p>long content</p>
  <p>long content</p>
  <p>long content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as intended when you replace `<br style="clear:both" />` with `<div style="clear:both"></div>`.

Seems to be a specialty in how Chrome handles `<br>`. The problem is that a `<br>` in chrome has width and height set to `auto`, which could possibly be something like zero.

When looking at [CSS Spec](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clear), I didn't find it unambiguously defined whether an empty element with height and width set to `auto` even has `sides of an element's box(es) [which] may not be adjacent to an earlier floating box.` But then, digging further, I found that the following will also work in Chrome:

```
<br style="clear: both; height:2px" />
```

while this "won't work", also in Firefox and IE (I got the CSS by looking at Chrome's default CSS for `<br>`):

```
<div style="display:inline; clear: both; width:auto; height:auto; "></div>
```

So this is not about CSS spec, but the (unresolved, unstandardized) question which default CSS styles to apply to which HTML element.

Comment: `<br style="clear: both; height:2px" />`
doesn't work on my system.